# google translate api error 403 in first time use

Tags: api, google-translate

i am the newer of google translate api. After creating a new project and getting the api key. the resonse always be the followings:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate/quotas?project=302824800783",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate/quotas?project=302824800783"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate/quotas?project=302824800783"
 }
}
```

this is the first time i use this api. I think i should have a 60 days free trail. Is there anyone tell me why?

Comment: got similar problem here. Hope someone be able to help.

Comment: apparently the api starts working after midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate API is a **paid enterprise service** for translating large amounts of text.

You can checkout official document [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart?csw=1).
Read warning on top.